# Aptana Studio 3 sorts editor tabs by activity

Tags: settings, aptana3

By default Aptana Studio 3 rearranges your open editor tabs (open files) by last activity, once too many are open and the available space is used up. I find this behavior totally unintuitive. Is there any way to change that?

I already tried changing presentation, theme and traditional style tabs options. None of them seem to affect the tab sorting. All I want is to keep the tabs in the order I opened them.

Comment: You can drag them to whatever order you want..

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Sarah. I already did try dragging to reorder my tabs. After opening even more files though, Aptana will remove the first tab if I haven't clicked it for a while. That's exactly the problem. I don't want Aptana to decide which tabs to show or hide. Seems like a UI/UX misconception if the user can't turn such a "feature" off.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about ordering tabs this way. You can use the ctrl + E shortcut to bring up the list of tabs, and you can limit the number of tabs that stay open and pin the ones you want which may make them stay where you put them... I believe tab ordering is one of the features that is straight from Eclipse so that is probably where you want to do your research rather than Aptana which has a much smaller audience. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fplatform_tips.html

Comment: Thanks again, Sarah. The reference to Eclipse helped a lot. I did more research on that fact and found an Eclipse plugin that works in Aptana and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Eclipse plugin which works in Aptana and disables tab sorting among other options.

[Extended VS Presentation plugin for Eclipse](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html)